# Only if in where clause (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to know how to do this:

```
WHERE (if @date is not null) date = @Date
```

It's only one condition to do if @date is not null else there is no condition to do. I read something like this

```
WHERE date = IIF (@Date IS NOT NULL, @date , )
```

But it doesn't work for this case.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full query?

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE (date = @Date OR @Date IS NULL)
```

This would check if your column is equal to the parameter; if the parameter is null, then date column wouldnt need to match with the parameter value

Comment: How do you know he isn't trying to make an assignment?

Answer (score 2):

Use CASE Statement in WHERE Clause instead of IFF

```
 SELECT * FROM Your_table
 WHERE Date = CASE WHEN @date IS NULL THEN Date ELSE @Date END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE Date=CASE WHEN @date IS NULL THEN Date ELSE @Date END
```